# difference between different c++ library method?

Tags: c++

As I know, we can write our c++ library in **.h** file,**.C** file and **.c &.h** file?
can someone describe difference between these  3 library method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a C++ library should no be in a `.c` file. That indicates C language. C++ source modules should generally have `.cpp` extension.
Then, common to both C and C++ language, a header file should have `.h` extension to denote that it is a header. Header files are used to define the APIs in your library; i.e., the names of functions and their parameters. The actual bodies of the various functions in your library should be in `.cpp` files. The API defined in the header file should match the function definitions in the `.cpp` files.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but templates are fundamentally different in this regard, and must be defined in headers.

Comment: @PeteBecker Agreed; my answer did not include templates, which must be in header files because the compiler needs all the code for a template instead of just the API definition.

Comment: the extensions are just convention. You can name your source files `.foo` and headers `.bar`, it wont change much

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number -- yes, in a sense, but some compilers use the extension to decide how to compile a source file -- .c gets compiled as C, and .cpp gets compiled as C++.

Comment: I recommend using `.hpp` or `.hxx` for C++ header files to differentiate from C language header files.  The C language does not like importing C++ header files.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah sure, my point was just that this answer seems to focus too much on the extensions but misses to explain why code is seperated in headers and source files, when this is applicable and when not

Comment: thanks a lot
please introduce document for more info